# Bernoulli Trials Probability Question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-numbers

I've been super stuck on this question for awhile now. Would really appreciate it if someone could break down the solution for me. Thanks!

> **Question**: Consider now the setting of independent Bernoulli trials, each with 
>   probability of success $p$. Let $S_i$ be the number of successes in the first $i$ trials. Compute $\mathbb E[S_m \mid S_n]$. (You will need to consider three cases based on whether $m > n$, $m = n$, or $m < n$. Try using your intuition rather than proceeding by calculations.)

Comment: Show your reasoning. Do you have an idea for the $m=n$ case? It should be obvious. What about the $m > n$ case? Say you know that you had 5 hits on the first $n=10$ attempts. What number of hits you expect for the first $m=30$ cases, if $p=0.4$ for instance?

Comment: I think @nicola is quite right that you should consider concrete values of $m, n, p$ to check that you understand the problem.  From your comments, it seems like you're not quite clear on what the terms mean...?

Comment: Yeah I just started to learn the concept, and this is just one of the practice problems I could find. I definitely don't have a good grasp yet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with calculating estimated values? Did you get the case $m = n $? That should be the easiest.

Notice that the outcome of each trial does not influence others and you have $P($success $) = p $.

Do they want exact values in function of $S_n$ or comparing $E[S_m | S_n] $ with $S_n $ is enough?

Comment: They want exact values in function of Sn. So I'm not really sure where to go but my intuition is that for m = n it would be E[n]. For m > n it would be E[m] and for n > m it would also be E[m]. But I feel like I'm wrong.

Comment: Suppose $m < n$, and $S_n = n$.  You wouldn't compute the conditional expectation of $S_m$ based on $P(\text{success}) = p$, would you?

Comment: @JackM: $m$ is a known value, so $E(m) = m$.  Is every trial a success?

Comment: so are you saying E(m) should be mp?

Comment: and for m > n, would this look right? E[m-n]p + Sn

Answer (score 0):

**Basic approach.**  If $m = n$, then $S_m = S_n$, so I expect you can finish that case.

If $m > n$, then there were $S_n$ successes in the first $n$ trials.  How many successes do you expect to see in the remaining $m-n$ trials?

If $m < m$, then the proportion of successes in the first $n$ trials was $q = \frac{S_n}{n}$.  If that same proportion were to hold in the first $m$ trials, how many successes would you expect?

Comment: So for m = n, would it just be mp? And for m > n, E[m-n]p + Sn?

Comment: @JackM: Keep in mind that $E(X)$, where $X$ is a random variable (or an expression of random variables) means "the expected value of $X$".  The expected value of $m-n$ is just $m-n$, since neither $m$ nor $n$ is a random variable in this problem.  But for $m > n$, you are right, the expression is just $(m-n)p+S_n$.

Comment: @JackM: For $m = n$, you're neglecting the fact that you know $S_n$.  This is why I recommended that you look at concrete cases.  Suppose $m = n = 5$ and $p = 0.5$.  Suppose you know $S_n = S_5 = 3$.  What is the expected value of $S_m = S_5$?  Don't you already know exactly what that is?

Comment: Ok so for $m = n$ , it should just be $S_n$. Now for $m < n$ would it be $(S_n / m)p$? Or am I lost.

Comment: @JackM: Close; you have the right form, but the wrong values.  Forget $p$.  Suppose $n = 10$, and $S_n = S_{10} = 6$.  What does that mean?  It means that there are $6$ successes in the first $10$ trials.  Now suppose $m = 5$.  What is the expected value of $S_m$—how many successes do you expect in the first $5$ trials, *given that you saw $6$ successes in the first $10$ trials*?

Comment: @JackM: In other words, it doesn't matter if $p = 0.00001$; if by some odd chance there were $6$ successes in the first $10$, and those successes are independent (as they must be in Bernoulli trials), then each of the first $10$ trials has a $6/10 = 0.6$ probability of being a success.  ETA: By the way you are right about $m = n$.

Comment: Ok I hope I understood lol. Would it be $(S_n/n)m$? So $(S_n/n)$ gives us the probability of a success of any trial, and we multiply it by $m$ trials?

Comment: @JackM: Yes, it gives the probability of success of any trial *in the first $n$ trials*.  After the first $n$ trials, since further trials are not affected by the condition, they succeed with probability $p$, whence the answer in the $m > n$ case.

Comment: Thanks so much. Makes a lot more sense now :)